# Why Orfox + Orbot sends UUID to Amazon/Mozilla?

Tags: anonymity

Any idea how this UUID has been generated and whether I could be identified with it.
This was sent in SSL when I open orfox. I captured it. After this one connecrion to mozilla, the traffic went through orbot and was encrypted.

GET /v1?uuid=013hulika6h-2078-489d-8dd2-dhh434e15fa&device=shamu&lang=eng&country=USA&manufacturer=motorola&appId=info.guardianproject.orfox&version=Fennec-45.5.1esr/TorBrowser-6.5-1/Orfox-1.2.1 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; Nexus 6 Build/NBD91P)
Host: switchboard-server.dev.mozaws.net

Comment: Do you have any addons installed? If no, then check the Orfox build - it seems to be a Play store mess-up. Get the latest APK *directly* from the guardian project https://guardianproject.info/releases/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be known issue. Nice. I think it's strange that it still exists. It should be the first thing to check. https://dev.guardianproject.info/issues/6585